# problem with using axios interceptors in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, xmlhttprequest, interceptor

I want to get **fetching status** when make and send requests using axios. I thought that I can achieve this by using **axios interceptors**. I try this code:

`./axiosInstance.js`

```js
let fetching = false;

const axiosInstance = axios.create();

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => { 
    fetching = true;
    console.log("first log: ", fetching);
    return config;
}, () => { fetching = false });

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(() => { 
    console.log("second log: ", fetching);
    fetching = false;
    console.log("third log: ", fetching);
});

export { fetching, axiosInstance };
```

And this is how I make and send requests using my own instance of axios that I created:

`./component.js`

```js
import { fetching, axiosInstance } from "./axiosInstance";

const Component = () => {

    const sendRequest = () => {
        axiosInstance.get("someUrl:somePort/");
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button type="button" onClick={ sendRequest }>click</button>
            <p>{ fetching ? "true": "false" }</p>
        </>
    );
}

export default Component;
```

But the problem is, this is not work. I get logs in `./axiosInstance.js` as I expected:

```js
first log: true
second log: true
third log: false
```

But I have a **<p>** tag in `./component.js` that I use it to show value of the *fetching* variable that I get it from `./axiosInstance.js`. and its value never change to true and it's always false.

```js
<p>{ fetching ? "true": "false" }</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);

const axiosInstance = axios.create();

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => { 
    setFetching(true);
    console.log("first log: ", fetching);
    return config;
}, () => { fetching = false });

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(() => { 
    console.log("second log: ", fetching);
    setFetching(false);
    console.log("third log: ", fetching);
});

export { fetching, axiosInstance };
```

You can use `fetching` as a state.
It will be working.